# script that applies a style to newly created elements

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am writing a tampermonkey script that changes the style of an element whose class starts with "blocked". So i have this code:

```
var blockedelements = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=blocked]");
var element = blockedelements[0];
element.style.display="none";
```

for simplicity this is only for the first element but i know how to iterate through each one and this code as it is works.  the webapp dynamically creates new elements with this class and i want the script to execute for each newly created element which is what i don't know how to do. I want a pure JS solution, not jquery. Is this what a listener is for? i don't know much about javascript.

I would appreciate any pointers, thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad, but as a tip, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration might also help if you are just getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually changing the display value for every instance of the element, you could use JavaScript to add a page-wide style rule to hide all of them. That way you can let the browser handle applying the rule to both existing and future instances of the element for you.

Rough idea:

```
var rule = "[class^=blocked] { display: none }";
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");

styleElement.type = "text/css";

if (styleElement.style.cssText) {
  styleElement.style.cssText = rule;
} else {
  styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rule));
}

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

Comment: doesn't this need a listener (or as someone pointed out) a mutation observer to monitor the creation of new nodes?

Comment: This is approach is basically like adding a new css file to the page that establishes that the browser should hide any element with a class starting with “blocked”. CSS is automatically applied to new element instances as they are added to the page.